# C Syntax for a dynamic-allocated array within a struct within a dynam array within a struct

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

I have a C syntax question which is driving me crazy.  I've defined some container structs:

```
typedef struct AStruct {
    int importantData1;
    int importantData2;
} A;

typedef struct BStruct {
    A* arr1;                // dynamic array of A structs
} B;

typedef struct CStruct {
    B* arr2;                // dynamic array of B structs
} C;
```

As you can guess, each A struct hold a part of my program's data.  Each B struct holds an array of A's and each C struct holds an array of B's.  I anticipate the need for only one C struct.  So total amount of data with my C struct will be:

```
total data in C  ==  (num of B's) * (num of A's)
```

The tricky part is I don't know how many A's and B's I'll need at compile time.  This means I can't hardwire the array sizes; they must be dynamically allocated.

There's gotta be a way to do this.  Here's my clunky attempt:

```
void makeContainers(C* x, int numB, int numA){
    x->arr2 = (B*)malloc(numB * sizeof(B));   // allocate an array of empty B structs
    B* Bptr;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<numB; i++){
            Bptr = x->arr2[i];                      // Bptr is one of the B's in C's arr2
            Bptr = (A*)malloc(numA * sizeof(A));    // Allocate an array of empty A stucts
    }
}

int main() {
    C* bigContainer = (C*)malloc(sizeof(C));    // Allocate the C struct
    makeContainers(bigContainer, 8, 8);         // populate C with B's and A's

    return 0;
}
```

This looked great on paper... but the compiler hates the `Bptr = x->arr2[i];` line.  (Compiling with GCC on Linux)  Here's the error:

```
[Linux]$ gcc -Wall setsInSets.c
setsInSets.c: In function ‘makeContainers’:
setsInSets.c:23:8: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct B *’ from type ‘B’
   Bptr = x->arr2[i];   // Bptr is one of the B's in C's arr2
        ^
```

The "***to type struct B from type B***" part confuses me.  Not sure what the compiler is trying to tell me here.

Also...  This is kinda a C 101-type question, but I'm not certain I completely understand what the first line in makeContainers() is doing:

```
x->arr2 = (B*)malloc(numB * sizeof(B));
```

Here I am allocating memory for an array of B structs... but does that mean when this command is finished, I literally have an array of "empty" B structs ready to go?  Or have I just set aside the memory, but the memory itself contains just "garbage"?  In other words, do I have to walk the `x->arr2` array and `malloc()` an individual B struct?

I know this is probably a duplicate question - but I ask it anyway because I think the "struct within a dynamic array within a struct within a dynamic array" nature of this question is pretty specific.

Thanks!
-Pete

Comment: `x->arr2[i]` evaluates to a `B` object, not a pointer. Maybe you meant to write `Bptr = x->arr2`?

Comment: [Don't cast malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Those are not arrays at all. They are structs so you can't do `x->arr2[i]` but if you want to access, for example, `importantData1`, you can actually do `x->arr2->arr1->importantData1`

Comment: `Bptr = x->arr2[i];`should be `Bptr = x->arr2 + i;` or `Bptr = &x->arr2[i];`

Comment: @Jezor Yes!  You're totally right.  I see it now.  Its so easy to misunderstand what your C pointer really dereferences to.  Thank you!

Comment: @NickRameau  Thanks Nick.  You are right about how it access importantData1.  Once I saw your answer, I realized what I'd done wrong.

Comment: @alk Yep, I you're totally right.  My syntax looks good now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x->arr2` is pointer to an array of B structs

`x->arr2[i]` is dereferencing one element in the array i.e. a B struct

To set a pointer you need the address of the struct

```
B* Bptr = &(x->arry[i]);
```

or more conveniently

```
B* Bptr = x->arry + i;
```

I would suggest you write the size of the array in your struct as well, it may come in handy later.

e.g.

```
typedef struct BStruct {
    size_t elements;        // to know how many A structs 
    A* arr1; 
} B;
```

EDIT:

This part of the code

```
Bptr = x->arr2 + i;         // Bptr is one of the B's in C's arr2
Bptr = malloc(numA * sizeof(A));
```

makes no sense, you first assign Bptr, then assigning it to another address.

Comment: This is very, very clear, thank you.  My syntax works now.  Adding the size into the struct is a stroke of genius, I've already implemented it.  Nice!